# When to apply Bonferroni correction?

Tags: statistical-significance, multiple-comparisons, bonferroni

I have 2 conditions, each with 2 factors, making 4 combinations. For each of these 4 combinations, I measure 6 variables.

For the sake of illustration, let's say I'm measuring the 'quality' of leaves on a tree. I'm measure two different kinds of trees (oak vs maple) and I use tries in two different locations (urban vs wilds). I measure 'leaf quality' with 6 variables (color, size, etc..)

I want to see if significant difference exists between these conditions, and thus I perform a simple t-test.

For example, is there a difference in the color (variable 1) of maple trees (condition 1, factor 1) for urban (condition 2, factor 1) and wild (condition 2, factor 1) trees?

I do 2 * 2 * 6=24 of these tests. To correctly apply Bonferroni's correction, should I divide my target alpha (0.05) by 24?

Comment: not an answer to your question, but you might consider doing MANOVA

Comment: Why do you compare oak in the urban condition to maple in the wilds condition? Why do you compare maple in the urban condition to oak in the wilds condition? It does not seem a fair comparison to me. I would compare the two types of trees keeping the location fixed (both urban or both wilds)